# Change Password/Confirm_Password Password Tips

Tags: 8, forms

How does one go about changing the Password Tips for the password_confirm form element?

This one specifically:

```
Recommendations to make your password stronger: 
•Make it at least 12 characters 
•Add lowercase letters
•Add uppercase letters 
•Add numbers 
•Add punctuation
```

Into something like:

```
Password should have: 
• Minimum of 12 characters 
• At least one lowercase letter
• At least one uppercase letter
• At least one number
• At least one special character
• No three consecutive same characters
```

I'm tried using the hook_element_info_alter() hook that calls a method my_module_form_process_password_confirm() and followed this template(https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_form_process_password_confirm/8.5.x).

But it doesn't seem to be working.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_element_info_alter().
 */
function client_element_info_alter(array &$types) {
  if (isset($types['password_confirm'])) {
    $types['password_confirm']['#process'][] = 'client_form_process_password_confirm';
  }
}

function client_form_process_password_confirm($element){
  if (($key = array_search('user_form_process_password_confirm', $element['#process'])) !== false) {
    unset($element['#process'][$key]);
  }
  $element['#process'] = array_values($element['#process']);

  $password_settings = [
    'confirmTitle' => t('Passwords match DOES IT:'),
    'confirmSuccess' => t('yes'),
    'confirmFailure' => t('no'),
    'showStrengthIndicator' => FALSE,
  ];

  $password_settings['showStrengthIndicator'] = TRUE;
  $password_settings += [
    'strengthTitle' => t('Password strength:'),
    'hasWeaknesses' => t('Password should have:'),
    'tooShort' => t('Minimum of 12 characters'),
    'addLowerCase' => t('At least one lowercase letter'),
    'addUpperCase' => t('At least one uppercase letter'),
    'addNumbers' => t('At least one number'),
    'addPunctuation' => t('At least one special character'),
    'sameAsUsername' => t('Make it different from your username'),
    'weak' => t('Weak'),
    'fair' => t('Fair'),
    'good' => t('Good'),
    'strong' => t('Strong'),
    'username' => \Drupal::currentUser()->getUsername(),
  ];

  $element['#attached']['library'][] = 'user/drupal.user';
  $element['#attached']['drupalSettings']['password'] = $password_settings;

  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

so I managed to tinker enough to get something to work and I'm sharing it in case other people need it or something. Of course, I dunno if this is optimal or follows standards or shouldn't even be done in the first place but please feel free to add your input. It's in the my_module.module file, by the by. Oh and don't mind the text, was just kinda testing this out and all that jazz.

Without further ado, here's the code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function <my_module>_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === <my_custom_form_id>) {
    // Note that this isn't actually a hook
    $form['#after_build'][] = '<my_module>_confirm_password_after_build';
  }
}

function client_confirm_password_after_build($element) {
  $drupal_settings = $element['pass']['#attached']['drupalSettings']['password'];

  $drupal_settings = [
    'confirmTitle'          => t('Do the passwords match?'),
    'confirmSuccess'        => t('Yeah'),
    'confirmFailure'        => t('Nope'),
    'showStrengthIndicator' => TRUE,
    'hasWeaknesses'         => t('Password Suggestions:'),
    'tooShort'              => t('Make it at least 50 characters'),
    'addLowerCase'          => t('Add 7 lowercase letters'),
    'addUpperCase'          => t('Add 8 uppercase letters'),
    'addNumbers'            => t('Add 8 numbers'),
    'addPunctuation'        => t('Add 10 punctuations'),
    'sameAsUsername'        => t(''),
    'weak' => t('Forgettable'),
    'fair' => t('Meh'),
    'good' => t('Almost'),
    'strong' => t('You got it'),
    'username' => '',
  ];

  $element['pass']['#attached']['drupalSettings']['password'] = $drupal_settings;
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enter link description here](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_policy)password_policy

If you wonder why your code isn't working then you should include the code in your question.